# Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array ---> Line 23

Tags: javascript, php, json

This code has been working for the last year and recently started giving the error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
in /nas/content/live/fincomms/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(446) : eval()'d code on **line 23**

Any ideas how to resolve? See code below.

```
21      if (!empty($hatchbuck_response) && !empty($hatchbuck_response['body'])) {
22      $hatchbuck_parsed = json_decode($hatchbuck_response['body']);
23      $contact_id = $hatchbuck_parsed[0]->contactId;
24      //echo $hatchbuck_parsed[0];
25      //die();
```

Comment: It looks like the top-level of `$hatchbuck_parsed` is not an array (perhaps it was an array with non-consecutive array indexes when it was originally encoded)

Comment: What's the output of `echo $hatchbuck_response['body']`?

Comment: Can you provide a `var_dump` of `$hatchbuck_parsed`?

Comment: You can use json_decode(data, true) to get a php array instead of an stdclass, but you may need to access a child property first depending on what you're parsing.

Comment: If this was working, what's changed? Start there.